# How can I configure Visual Studio to fix selected analyzer warnings on save?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 17.6.3 and .NET 7.0. I want to auto-format my C# code on save.

I can configure *Code Cleanup* to *Run code cleanup profile on save*. The available fixers provide some very basic fixes for formatting. But I have more advanced formatting settings in my `.editorconfig` file: .NET's code quality rules, and formatting rules from the third-party library *Roslynator.Formatting.Analyzers*. Both provide fixes. I could add *Fix analyzer warnings and errors set in EditorConfig* to the code cleanup profile's fixes, but then also other fixes unrelated to formatting would be applied, which I do not want at that stage.

There is the *CSharpier* extension which allows me to perform advanced formatting on save, but it is too opinionated for my taste and will ignore rule from analyzers.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I found an extension plugin that can meet your needs:

Open visual studio - Extensions - Manage Extensions - Online - Search Format document on Save

After downloading, you need to restart visual studio.

Comment: How could that extension help? In its options there is no way to specify which rules/fixes to apply.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein Hello, [Format document on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave) can format the code when saving it. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Yes, but that is not sufficient. Recent versions of Visual Studio can do that without an extension. I need to also apply fixes for additional (possibly third-party) formatting rules that are configured in my `.editorconfig` - fixes which are not covered by what Visual Studio does when formatting.

Comment: @MarcoEckstein Sorry, I will look for other extensions